# Put text between autofilled PHP-Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm currently working on a table that contains *'Name', 'Info', 'Price' and 'Duration'*. However the PHP-Script is connected to a database.

I want to autofill the tablecells: 'Name', 'Price', 'Duration' via the Database by using PHP and SQL and that **works perfectly fine for me**. Though, I want to customize the content that's in the individual Info cells (e.g. Readmore jQuery and redirect to other pages).

I tried a little bit with using tags inside the Database and other weird stuff which, obviously, didn't work.

Is there a more elegant way of solving my problem than setting up a complete normal table without PHP/SQL, where I'd have to put in every bit of data about Name,Price and Duration manually?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter row sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header">Name</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Info</th>
        <th>Price (in Euro)</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php


//Connect to Database
$db=mysql_connect ("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die ('Oops! Da hat wohl' . mysqli_error(). 'Mist gebaut'); 

//Choose Database
$mydb=mysql_select_db("massageke_de");

//Query Database
$sql="SELECT * FROM Angebote";


//-run the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

//Show Results
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


//Start table ?>

<tr>
        <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Name =$row['Name'] ; ?></td>

        <!--In this <td>-tag I want to put long textes with links-->
        <td class="hidden-xs col-sm-5">echo $Name =$row['Info'];?<</td> 

        <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Preis =$row['Preis']; ?></td>
        <td ckass="col-sm-1"><?php echo $Dauer =$row['Dauer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>


    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Thanks in advance for helping.
Don't bother asking me additional questions.

P.S.:  I hope you can help, without needing the CSS of Bootstrap, that I used.

P.P.S.:I know that my PHP-Script is not protected against PHP-Injection 
*(but I want to and will learn how to secure it)*

Edit: As Jester asked for it. I made it quickly with photoshop because I think an image can express much better, what I want to achieve, than my poorly coding-skills.
[Get to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGAbQ.jpg)

Comment: you want to customize it for reach row but you don't want to do it manually? if you want to customize it for each row you have to do it manually, if it's dependent on certain variables then you can automate it. Can you show us what you'd like as a result with a small data set?

Comment: @Jester I added one via imgur. Hope it helps. Thank you

Comment: couldn't you just edit the info fields? or you don't have access to the database?

Comment: @justin I do have in fact acess to the Databse. But the texts, I have to implement, are so long, that for design reasons I need an Readmore.js script in the info text-section and/or an <a href="#">-tag. And that didn't work nor does it look decent.

Comment: i doubt that you'd ever reach the limit of a `MEDIUMTEXT` field let alone a Long one, but nevertheless i posted another suggestion which should work i think

Comment: little p.s. "Thanks in advance for helping. Don't bother asking me additional questions." this suggests that you don't want people to bother you with questions. which i hope is just a mistake in english and not meant like that :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like the easiest way would be to just edit the info column in the database for each? If you want to do it in php i'd suggest making an array using the names (ids would be better but it seems you don't have access to those?) as keys:

```
$info['Aroma Teilkoerper'] = "Text about aroma teilkoerper";
$info['Aroma Ganzkoerper'] = "Text about aroma ganzkoerper";
```

and so on until you have all. Then in the loop:

```
//Show Results
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


//Start table ?>

<tr>
    <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Name =$row['Name'] ; ?></td>

    <!--In this <td>-tag I want to put long textes with links-->
    <td class="hidden-xs col-sm-5">echo $Name =$info[$row['Name']];?></td> 

    <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Preis =$row['Preis']; ?></td>
    <td ckass="col-sm-1"><?php echo $Dauer =$row['Dauer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Hoping that is a workable solution for you? (also you had a syntax error in your closing php tag.

```
echo $Name =$row['Info'];?<  // <----- should be ?> of course
```

Comment: Yes. I don't know why i didn't think of arrays in the way you did, but this is exactly what I just needed. Thank you so much!

Edit: By the way I do have the acess to the IDs and applied your code with IDs. Works perfect!